# Cannot deregister AMI from AWS, "an error occurred attempting to deregister amis". Does anyone know the reason and provide a solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am attempting to clear my snapshots and AMI from AWS account, to delete snapshots i understand one needs to de-register the AMIs. But when i try to de-register through console, i am given the below error.
"an error occurred attempting to deregister amis"

Anyone has an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem (and I've seen it reported on AWS forums too). The issue is that the console doesn't refresh after you deregister the AMIs. Thus they are deregistered the first time, but they are still listed as if they are there. If you try to deregister them again it fails and gives the warning (as they were already deregistered).

Solution: after clicking 'deregister' click the 'refresh' button at the top right corner of the console (at the same level as the 'Actions' drop down).

Comment: Wow, that really caught me. I wish they were automatically refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but even getting this error message, the AMIs got de-registered.
Then I was able to delete snapshots.

You may have success trough eb cli.
I've found this tutorial from AWS (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/deregister-ami.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly same problem. Deregister it from console failed.
Try to deregister it from cli: **aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id <ami_id>** then you'll see the exact message that prevent it. In my case there's still Backup vaults link to my AMI. After removing the backup vaults from AWS Backup, problem solved.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were down-voted, but this is the exact issue that i had - Thank you!  
Maybe add the error message: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DeregisterImage operation: This image is managed by AWS Backup and cannot be deleted via EC2 APIs. To delete this image, please use the AWS Backup APIs, CLI, or console.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have de-registered the AMIs, it takes some time to reflect on the console.
Even refreshing again and again doesn't work in some cases. 
The best solution is to LEAVE IT and wait patiently...it will go away by itself.